# How to push information into multidirectional array using jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have Purchase Table like following.

**Item** **QTY** **Rate** **Amnt**
ABC        2       100      200 
DEF        1       300      300

When save Button is clicked, I want this information to be stored in multi directional array like
Array[0][0] = ABC
Array[0][1] = 2
Array[0][2] = 100
Array[0][3] = 100
Array[1][0] = DEF
Array[1][0] = 1
Array[1][1] = 300
Array[1][3] = 300

Please help me out how I can assign like this using jquery.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please read the [tour] and [ask] page.

Comment: Loop through each tr then inside each loop through each td - the `.each()` https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function function nicely includes the index so you can assign the array directly.

Answer (score 1):

The final JS code depends on the HTML structure of your table, but the data grabbing logic might be as follows:

```js
// Add click event listener
$('#saveBtn').on("click", function() {
  const tbody = $('#myTable tbody');
  const resultData = [];
  
  // Loop through each tr
  $('tr', tbody).each(function(rowIndex) {
    const trElement = $(this);
    const rowData = []
    
    // Loop through each td
    $('td', trElement).each(function(colIndex) {
      const tdElement = $(this);
      rowData[colIndex] = tdElement.text();
    });
    
    resultData[rowIndex] = rowData;
  });
  
  console.log(resultData);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Possible HTML code of the table:</p>

<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Amnt</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DEF</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td>300</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input id="saveBtn" type="button" value="save">
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have one problem in looping through each td. One td has text while other three tds are input and takes value in them. I can not use rowData[colIndex] = tdElement.text(); for all of them.

Comment: You can check if there is an input field in the cell and if so, take a value of it. Take a look https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/jOqxeOO